# Postmaster CRON notification

Tags: postmaster, notification, cron

I'm new to postmaster. I've been using MX Notify to do some basic notifications. However, I'm looking to to send a "reminder email" that will trigger a CRON timer of +3 days after a initial email is sent. Is this possible with Postmaster? I haven't wrapped my head around how hooks, parcels, etc should be aligned yet. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible with Postmaster. You would setup two parcels. The first would be the immediate email. Don't worry about sending this email later. Create a new Parcel (or duplicate) and set that second Parcel to send in the future using the relative date field. You can set it to "+3 days" and it will recognize it and put the email in the queue for the appropriate time.

Then you just use the Ping url provided in the CP and setup a CRON job to ping it at your specified interval. You could also use the Notifications API, but this is much more advanced and probably overkill for what you need.

If you have any more questions or feedback you would like answered privately, feel free to email support[at]objectivehtml.com.

Comment: I'll five this a try, Justin. Like I said, I'm trying to wrap my head around how postmaster works. :)